# Need to maintain execution plans on SQL Server Upgrade 2017 to 2019

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2019, plan-cache

We are working on a performance issue and need to maintain the execution plans for troubleshooting. Need to maintain the execution plans and ensure the plan cache is not flushed out on upgrade to 2019.

Does the plan cache get cleared during an upgrade? is there a way to maintaining and ensuring the execution plans do not get cleared?

Answer (score 6):

The plan cache doesn't persist across service restarts. Since upgrading requires a service restart, there is no way to maintain the plan cache across version upgrades.

Your best bet is to ensure the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) is enabled, and then follow Microsoft's recommendations for [using the Query Store after an upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15).

After the upgrade, if you notice plan regressions, you can use the Query Store to force a historical plan that had better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Plan cache lives in memory. So, it doesn't survive an upgrade.

Turn on Query Store and let it record your queries and plans. That data is inside the database, so iit survives and upgrade.